# Iterating over awk return and running a command on each item

Tags: bash, awk, xargs

I would like to take a list of instance names I've received by using awk and delete them one by one. I have extracted the instance names via their respective column and ignored the column header name. I've got the list of instance names, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to run the delete command on each of these names. I believe awk is returning a big string, but I'm at a loss as to how to split the string up and run it through my delete command.

Here is the line that doesn't work

```
 multipass list | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR!=1 {print}' | xargs -0 multipass delete
```

Here is the return I'm getting

```
instance "k3s
node1
node2
symfony
" does not exist
```

Comment: What does the result of the `multipass list` command look like?

Comment: `awk` can handle the entire process without being piped to multiple processes. Within `awk` you can use `system (rm" "filename)` to remove the file from within `awk`. Any time you are using `awk` and find yourself doing `process | process2 | process3 | ...`, it is likely it can all be done in a single call to `awk`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ITYM `system ("rm -- \047"filename"\047")` otherwise `rm` is an empty variable and the shell is getting `filename` unquoted and would fail if it started with `-`.

Comment: With `xargs -0` you're telling xargs that the input is NUL-delimited instead of newline-delimited - just don't do that.

Comment: @EdMorton - good catch, I knew there was a reason I always used `sprintf()` first...

Comment: @Dominique I have somehow deleted the instances with one of my experiments so they are all showing delete

Comment: @EdMorton Was i wrong with using xargs to handle the deletion? Can't xargs call multipass in paralell?

Comment: @AndrewBenavides not necessarily, where you went wrong was adding the `-0` argument to `xargs`. AFAIK `xargs` doesn't call anything in parallel, just in batches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
multipass list | awk 'NR!=1 {system("multipass delete "$2"")}'
```

Comment: That's passing `$2` unquoted to the shell for interpretation and so open to globbing, filename expansion, and security issues. Always quote any string you're using in shell, e.g. `system("multipass delete \047"$2"\047")`